# Как ходить по полю сапёра?

Tags: python, list

Буду очень признателен за любые подсказки и помощь. Пытался выложить идеи в код, но он перегружен if и я не понимаю как связать всё воедино.

Необходимо реализовать следующую функцию:

```
  import copy    
    def walk(minefield, moves, lives):
            """
            Make moves on the minefield.

            This function cannot modify the original minefield list.
            Starting position is marked by #.
            There is always exactly one # on the field.
            The position you start is an empty cell (".").

            Moves is a list of move "orders":
            N - up,
            S - down,
            E - right,
            W - left.

            Example: "NWWES"

            If the position you have to move contains "x" (small mine),
            then the mine is cleared (position becomes "."),
            but you cannot move there.
            In case of clearing a small mine, ff the position where the minesweeper is, has 5 or more mines nearby
            (see the previous function), minesweeper also loses a life.
            If it has 0 lives left, then clearing is not done and moving stops.

            Example:
            #x
            ..
            moves: ESS

            =>

            1st step ("E"):
            #.
            ..

            2nd step ("S"):
            ..
            #.

            3rd step ("S"):
            ..
            #.

            Example #2
            XXX
            x.x
            .#X
            moves: NWES, lives = 1

            1) "N"
            XXX
            x#x
            ..X

            2) "W". the small mine is cleared, but with the cost of one life :'(
            XXX
            .#x
            ..X
            lives = 0

            3) "E"
            XXX
            .#x
            ..X
            As clearing the mine on the right, he would lose a life (because minesweeper has 5 or more mines nearby).
            But as he has no lives left, he stops there. No more moves will be carried out.

            If the position you have to move contains "X" (huge mine),
            then you move there and lose a life.

            #X
            ..
            moves: ESS

            1) (lives = lives - 1)
            .#
            ..
            2)
            ..
            .#
            3)
            ..
            .#

            If you have to move into a position with a huge mine "X"
            but you don't have any more lives, then you finish your moves.

            lives: 2

            #XXXX
            .....
            moves: EEES

            1) lives = 1
            .#XXX
            .....
            2) lives = 0
            ..#XX
            .....
            3) stop, because you would die
            final result:
            ..#XX
            .....

            :param minefield:
            :param moves:
            :param lives:
            :return:
            """
```

Я вначале нахожу позицию # и записываю т.н. координаты и уже работаю с листом без #. # добавляется в конце

> `mf = copy.deepcopy(minefield)`
>
> ```
>             row = 0
>             col = 0
>             for i in range(len(mf)):
>                 for j in range(len(mf[i])):
>                     if mf[i][j] == '#':
>                         mf[i][j] = '.'
>                         row += i
>                         col += j
>
>             new_row, new_col = row, col
>             for move in moves:
>                 if move == 'N':
>                     new_row = row - 1
>                 elif move == 'S':
>                     new_row = row + 1
>                 elif move == 'W':
>                     new_col = col - 1
>                 elif move == 'E':
>                     new_col = col + 1
>                 for m in move:
>                     if mf[new_row][new_col] == 'x':
>                         mf[new_row][new_col] = '.'
>                             lives -= 1
>                     elif mf[new_row][new_col] == '.':
>                         continue
>                     elif mf[new_row][new_col] == 'X':
>                         if lives == 0:
>                             break
>                         else:
>                             continue
>             mf[new_row][new_col] = '#'
>             return mf
> ```

Логика описана в docstring, поле следующее:

```
minefield = [
            ['.', '.', 'x', '.', '.'], 
            ['.', '.', 'x', '.', '.'], 
            ['.', '.', 'x', '.', '.'], 
            ['.', '.', 'x', '.', '.'], 
            ['.', '.', 'x', '.', '.']
            ]
```

ставим условную фигуру на поле(это может быть любое свободное от Х место на поле)

```
mf[0][0] = '#'
```

вызов этой функции даёт следующий результат:

```
print(walk(mf, 'WEESE', 2)) ->

[
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
['.', '#', '.', '.', '.'], 
['.', '.', 'x', '.', '.'], 
['.', '.', 'x', '.', '.'], 
['.', '.', 'x', '.', '.']
]
```

Comment: Непонятен первый пример, с полем 2х2 и набором команд `moves: ESS`. Сапёр должен сделать два хода вниз, но после первого хода вниз он упирается в нижнюю границу поля. После второй команды "вниз" он просто остаётся на месте, ошибки "движение вниз невозможно" не происходит. Всё ли здесь верно?

Comment: да, всё верно, если следующее движение сапёра упирается в границу поля, то это движение игнорируется и он остаётся на месте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш код разбирать не стал, решил задачу по своему. Посмотрите, проверьте, если будет непонятно, как работает, пишите, я добавлю комментарии.

```
from pprint import pprint
import copy

class Sapper(object):
    def __init__(self, lives):
        self.lives = lives
        self.position = None
        self.commands = {
                            'N' : {'x' :  0, 'y' : -1},
                            'S' : {'x' :  0, 'y' : +1},
                            'E' : {'x' : +1, 'y' :  0},
                            'W' : {'x' : -1, 'y' :  0},
                        }
    def walk(self, mf, moves):
        self.mf = copy.deepcopy(mf)

        self.position = self.find_start_position()
        if self.position is None:
            print("You should set start position.")
            return

        for command in moves:
            self.move(command)
            if self.lives <= 0:
                break

        return self.mf

    def find_start_position(self):
        for i, row in enumerate(self.mf):
            for j, char in enumerate(row):
                if char == '#':
                    return {'x' : j, 'y' : i}

    def count_mines_around(self, x, y):
        neighbors = [
                        (-1, -1), (0, -1), (+1, -1),
                        (-1,  0),          (+1,  0),
                        (-1, +1), (0, +1), (+1, +1)
                    ]
        cnt = 1
        for n_y, n_x in neighbors:
            n_y += y
            n_x += x
            if self.check_borders(n_x, n_y):
                if self.mf[n_y][n_x] != '.':    
                    cnt += 1
        return cnt

    def move(self, command):
        x_next = self.position['x'] + self.commands[command]['x']
        y_next = self.position['y'] + self.commands[command]['y']

        if not self.check_borders(x_next, y_next):
            return

        if self.mf[y_next][x_next] == 'x':
            if self.count_mines_around(x_next, y_next) >= 5:
                self.lives -= 1
            self.mf[y_next][x_next] = '.'
        else:
            if self.mf[y_next][x_next] == 'X':
                self.lives -= 1 

            self.mf[self.position['y']][self.position['x']] = '.'
            self.mf[y_next][x_next] = '#'

            self.position['x'] = x_next
            self.position['y'] = y_next

    def check_borders(self, x, y):
        return 0 <= y < len(self.mf) and 0 <= x < len(self.mf[0])

def walk(minefield, moves, lives):
    sapper = Sapper(lives)
    return sapper.walk(minefield, moves)
```

**Тестирование:**

```
### Видоизменённая функция walk для тестирования
def walk(minefield, moves, lives):
    sapper = Sapper(lives)
    print("Lives were: ", sapper.lives)
    result_mf = sapper.walk(minefield, moves)
    print("Lives left: ", sapper.lives)
    return result_mf

##########################################    
print("\nExample №1")
minefield = [
                ['#', '.', 'x', '.', '.'],
                ['.', '.', 'x', '.', '.'],
                ['.', '.', 'x', '.', '.'],
                ['.', '.', 'x', '.', '.'],
                ['.', '.', 'x', '.', '.']
            ]
pprint(walk(minefield, 'WEESE', 2), width=30)

##########################################
print("\nExample №2")
minefield = [
                ['#', '.', 'x', 'x', '.'],
                ['.', 'x', 'x', 'x', '.'],
                ['.', '.', 'x', '.', '.'],
                ['.', '.', 'x', '.', '.'],
                ['.', '.', 'x', '.', '.']
            ]

pprint(walk(minefield, 'WEESE', 2), width=30)

##########################################    
print("\nExample from the task №1")
minefield = [
                ['#', 'x',],
                ['.', '.',],
            ]
pprint(walk(minefield, 'ESS', 2), width=20)

##########################################    
print("\nExample from the task №2")
minefield = [
                ['X', 'X', 'X',],
                ['x', '.', 'x',],
                ['.', '#', 'X',],
            ]

pprint(walk(minefield, 'NWES', 1), width=30)

##########################################    
print("\nExample from the task №3")
minefield = [
                ['#', 'X',],
                ['.', '.',],
            ]
pprint(walk(minefield, 'ESS', 2), width=20)

##########################################    
print("\nExample from the task №4")
minefield = [
                ['#', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X',],
                ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.',],
            ]
pprint(walk(minefield, 'EEES', 2), width=30)
```

**Output**

```
Example №1
Lives were:  2
Lives left:  2
[['.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '#', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', 'x', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', 'x', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', 'x', '.', '.']]

Example №2
Lives were:  2
Lives left:  1
[['.', '.', '#', 'x', '.'],
 ['.', '.', 'x', 'x', '.'],
 ['.', '.', 'x', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', 'x', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', 'x', '.', '.']]

Example from the task №1
Lives were:  2
Lives left:  2
[['.', '.'],
 ['#', '.']]

Example from the task №2
Lives were:  1
Lives left:  0
[['X', 'X', 'X'],
 ['.', '#', '.'],
 ['.', '.', 'X']]

Example from the task №3
Lives were:  2
Lives left:  1
[['.', '.'],
 ['.', '#']]

Example from the task №4
Lives were:  2
Lives left:  0
[['.', '.', '#', 'X', 'X'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
```

Comment: Честно, то как Вы написали код, это тот уровень к которому мне ещё расти. Я многого в нём пока ещё не понимаю, поэтому спрашивать и узнавать что каждая строчка делает не буду) Но на основе вашего кода я написал громоздкое, но работающее решение. 

Спасибо!